# Find consecutives values in an array and create an array grouped by their count

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, loops, populate

I have this kind of array :

```
[0 => 0, 1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 1, 4 => 1, 5 => 0, 6 => 0]
```

So its areas of `0` intersected by areas of `1` but I'm only interested in areas of `0`

So what I try to achieve is group each of values which is 0 into another array of counts like this :

```
[Group1 => 3, Group2 => 2]
```

what I have done so far :

```
$arrayGroups = [];
for($i=0;$i < count($myArr);$i++) {
  if($myArr[$i] == 0 && $myArr[$i+1] != 1) {
    (isset($arrayGroups [0])) ? $arrayGroups [0] += 1 : $arrayGroups [0] = 1;
  }
}
```

It pretty work, but I'm blocked on how to populate the array with more groups

Thanx for helping

Comment: I don't quite see what exactly you try in your attempt, but you could do something like this: https://3v4l.org/MGRPk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter variable that you increment whenever a new group starts.

```
$counter = 0;
$in_group = false;
$arrayGroups = [];
foreach ($myArr as $val) {
    if ($val == 0) {
        if ($in_group) {
            $arrayGroups[$counter]++;
        } else {
            $in_group = true;
            $counter++;
            $arrayGroups[$counter] = 1;
        }
    } else {
        $in_group = false;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/alUgkB)